# How to write a Ruby regexp for [A-Z0-9] repeat 3, or 4 times, no more?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to detect `3P4`, `4SC3`, etc., but not `492-as`. I tried  `/[A-Z0-9]{3,4}/` but `492-as` is still passing.

If anyone could help me with this regexp rule, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean `492-as` passes?

Comment: @anubhava that was it. Can you answer it so I can accept? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use start and end of string anchors:

```
/\A[A-Z0-9]{3,4}\z/
```

See [demo at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/SSaMoWbPTz)

The `\A` forces the match at the beginning of a string, and `\z` matches the end of string.